# java.awt.HeadlessException showing Swing Application

Tags: java, swing, servlets, awt, headless

I have 2 applications. One is web app. another is Java standalone app.  Here I am calling Java app. through Servlet app. In stand alone app., I am using `JFrame`, `JPanel` etc. like Swing, AWT API. Here I am getting:

```
java.awt.HeadlessException
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:159)
at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:432)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:403)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:368)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:158)
```

For this I have set in Servlet app. is:

```
  System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
```

But Still I am getting same Issue. I am Glassfish Server. Can you guys please suggest me what I have to do?

Comment: Try to start your server with this property. Probably you set it too late.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to launch a GUI from a servlet? This is a VERY bad idea, IMHO.

Comment: Can You Please tell me,what i have to do now?..@GyroGearless

Comment: Can i update to true...@SergiyMedvynskyy

Comment: Sure. Don't launch a GUI from within servlet. But this perhaps not the answer you want ;-)

Comment: Can you use [tag:java-web-start]?

Comment: just move to tomcat

Answer (score 0):

I have already passed this problem before , Just Switch from **GlassFish** to **Tomcat** , And then your problem has been solved.